# Traducción del inglés "token" (compiladores)

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, informática

En el ámbito de los compiladores e intérpretes de lenguajes, existe el concepto de "token", que es cada una de las partes en que se divide una cadena en un lenguaje formal durante el análisis léxico. Posteriormente, (por lo general) tiene lugar un análisis sintáctico que parte de estos "tokens" para construir un árbol sintáctico, que luego se interpreta o se traduce a una representación distinta.

Por ejemplo, en

> resultado = unNúmero + otroNúmero;

Los "tokens" que se obtendrían del análisis léxico del ejemplo anterior podrían ser (los pongo separados por comas):

> resultado, =, unNúmero, +, otroNúmero, ;

¿Cómo podría traducirse al español la palabra "token" en este contexto? He pensado "símbolo", pero ya existe el concepto de "symbol" o "símbolo" con un significado distinto (cada uno de los identificadores utilizados en un programa, como en este caso "resultado", "unNúmero" y "otroNúmero").

Comment: fuera del contexto de informática un token es también la moneda específica o 'ficha' que se mete en los carritos del supermercado para desencajarlos, te valdría ficha en este caso también? A mí me suena que podría valer subcadena o cadena siempre y cuando cumpla ciertas condiciones, pero no me sale ninguna palabra fija

Comment: Ficha no es una idea tan mala, pero me parece... inusual. Subcadena no, porque cualquier secuencia de caracteres contenida en la de entrada sería una subcadena.

Comment: eso mismo pienso yo. Trabajo en el mundo del software en UK, y entiendo perfectamente el dilema, sin embargo uso tanto el inglés por trabajo que ya tengo el español olvidado

Comment: According to Wikipedia Spanish uses token as well https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_(inform%C3%A1tica)

Comment: Token tiene tres sentidos: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/t/token.htm#:~:text=A%20token%20may%20refer%20to,and%20devices%20on%20the%20network.

Comment: What is a token?
A **lexical token** is a sequence of characters that can be treated as a unit in the grammar of the programming languages.

Example of tokens:

Type token (id, number, real, . . . )
Punctuation tokens (IF, void, return, . . . )
Alphabetic tokens (keywords) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-lexical-analysis/#:~:text=What%20is%20a%20token%3F,%2C%20real%2C%20.%20.%20.%20)

Answer (score 4):

Como se dice en los comentarios, muchos artículos usan la palabra en inglés: *token*. Este [artículo de Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analizador_l%C3%A9xico) lo llama *componente léxico*:

> Un **analizador léxico** o **analizador lexicográfico** (en inglés *scanner*) es la primera fase de un compilador, consistente en un programa que recibe como entrada el código fuente de otro programa (secuencia de caracteres) y produce una salida compuesta de *tokens* (componentes léxicos) o símbolos.

Para mí, "componente léxico" o "unidad léxica" son buenas traducciones porque capturan el significado bastante bien.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo un token es —en el contexto de un compilador— una unidad representativa, un alias simbólico, un elemento ( santo y seña, a los fínes prácticos) substitutivo de otro.

Quizás le cabria **"*sema*"**, como elemento-signo, que sirve para identificar algo con un sentido que un sistema entiende.

> [sema](https://dle.rae.es/sema?m=form)
>
> Del al. Sema, y este del gr. σῆμα sêma 'señal'.
>
> 1. m. Ling. Unidad mínima de significado léxico o gramatical.

Answer (score 1):

La RAE considera que la palabra *token* es un extranjerismo que podría traducirse de distintas formas según el contexto, pero también utilizarse tal cual según [publicó en Twitter](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/1145979151494590466) en 2019. La Fundéu publicó recientemente [un artículo al respecto](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/token-alternativas-en-espanol/) en el que defiende que la palabra ya está suficientemente asentada como para poder considerarse adaptada al castellano, bien como *token*, bien como *toquen*. Supongo que el hecho de que la palabra tenga un sonido natural en español (de hecho, es homófona con *toquen*, del verbo *tocar*) contribuye a ello.

En todo caso, no creo que deba utilizarse en español fuera del ámbito informático. En otros casos sí tiene buenas equivalencias. Por ejemplo, en un casino llamaríamos *ficha* a lo que en inglés se llama *token*. O la expresión *a token effort*, que traduciríamos como *un esfuerzo simbólico*.

Answer (score 0):

Si aceptáis el comentario de un viejo informático (desde 1971) siempre he usado el termino **token** tal cual para describir cada uno de los *elementos* o *símbolos* de un lenguaje. O para el *testigo* que se pasa en algunos tipos de redes locales.

Ver **token** en http://www.tugurium.com/gti/termino.php?Tr=token

Es de esos términos, que como software, ya se han quedado.

Answer (score 0):

**ENGLISH**

What is a token?
A lexical token is a sequence of characters that can be treated as a unit in the grammar of the programming languages.

Example of tokens:

Type token (id, number, real, . . . )
Punctuation tokens (IF, void, return, . . . )
Alphabetic tokens (keywords)

[lexical token](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-lexical-analysis/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20a%20token%3F,%2C%20real%2C%20.%20.%20.%20)

**SPANISH**

> 2.1. Funciones del analizador léxico. Analizador léxico (scanner): lee la secuencia de caracteres del programa fuente, caracter a
> caracter, y los agrupa para formar unidades con significado propio,
> los **componentes léxicos** (**tokens en inglés**). Estos componentes
> léxicos representan:
>
> - palabras reservadas: if, while, do, . . .
> - identificadores: asociados a
>   variables, nombres de funciones, tipos definidos por el usuario,
>   etiquetas,... Por ejemplo: posición, velocidad, tiempo, . . .
> - operadores: = * + - / == > < & ! = . . .
> - símbolos especiales: ; ( ) [ ] { } ...
> - constantes numéricas: literales que representan valores
>   enteros, en coma flotante, etc, 982, 0xF678, -83.2E+2,...
> - constantes de caracteres: literales que representan cadenas concretas de
>   caracteres, “hola mundo”,...
>
> El analizador léxico opera bajo petición del analizador sintáctico
> devolviendo un componente léxico conforme el analizador sintáctico lo
> va necesitando para avanzar en la gramática.

[informática](http://informatica.uv.es/docencia/iiguia/asignatu/2000/PL/2008/tema2.pdf)