# ¿Qué palabra en español puede usarse para describir lo que representa "token", en la informática?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, informática, inglés

En los lenguajes de programación, existe los "tokens" que pueden entenderse como cadenas de caracteres que poseen un significado coherente para un determinado lenguaje de programación (*cfr.* [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448661/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-token), [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-token-in-programming)) y éstos forman parte de los componentes léxicos del propio lenguaje de programación. ¿Qué palabra puede usarse para describir en el lenguaje español, lo que representa un token en la lengua inglesa y específicamente en el campo de la informática?

Agradezco su apoyo.

Comment: Ya hay una pregunta similar: [Traducción del inglés "token" (compiladores)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/33019/6915). Pero al parecer no se refiere al mismo "token".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Qué palabra puede usarse para describir en el lenguaje español, lo que representa un token en la lengua inglesa y específicamente en el campo de la informática?

---

Aunque el concepto "token" ha ido ampliándose hacia otros ámbitos, tradicionalmente en informática el término, "token", se ha venido conociendo como "**componente léxico**", aunque dicho así, desnudo de contexto, parece un poco complicado de entender. Es por ello este un resumen general para entender el concepto propiamente dicho y aplicar un nombre con vinculación y sentido.

---

Según el "Wiktionary", token derivaría del inglés medieval token, taken, del inglés antiguo "tācn" como señal, dar en señal, prenda...

Esto es interesante para ir entendiendo la palabra "token"/"tokens". Los "tokens", son algo simbólico que nos sirve para intercambiar algo por otra cosa. Así "token" en inglés también se traduce por "**ficha**".

En español o inglés los "tokens" o "fichas" pueden ser;

- fichas de casino
- fichas de metro
- fichas de teléfono (antiguamente utilizadas)

Es decir, las "fichas" son ciertas unidades o individualidades que poseen un determinado valor cuando son utilizadas en ciertos ámbitos (casino, metro, teléfono...ropero)

Incluso una "**ficha de ropero**" puede ser considerada como "**token**", ya que una vez que se entrega la prenda, la "**ficha**" adquiere el valor de esa prenda mientras se mantiene depositada en el ropero, valor que antes no tenía, pudiendo cualquier persona que se encontrará tal "ficha", intercambiarla por la prenda depositada.

---

**Comprendiendo los "tokens" o "fichas" a través de un ejemplo en la vida real**.

Imaginemos **una lavandería** con cierta capacidad, donde existe una "zona de entregas" de las prendas textiles que están depositadas.

Las prendas textiles de la lavandería están organizadas por números y letras.

Imaginemos que la lavandería divide, organiza y cataloga sus prendas en función de;

- Textil de Hostelería. (H)
- Textil de Residencias y Colegios. (R)
- Textil de Particulares. (P)
- Textiles Especiales (para prendas delicadas y fuertes manchas). (E)

Si un cliente con objeto de recoger una prenda, llegara y nos entregara su "**ficha**" **H10230**, podríamos leer que en esa ficha aparece escrito una especie de código que hace referencia a unas letras y números que apuntan a un lugar o dirección **H10230** o al menos tiene cierto significado para alguien.

La persona encargada de entregar la prenda, analizaría antes ese código y se fijaría que esa prenda textil es (H), es decir, que pertenece al grupo de "**Hostelería**" y que se encuentra en el 10230, pudiendo tener cada número un valor, sentido o connotaciones distinta para referirse a prendas determinadas. Una vez analizada la "ficha" se dirigiría al lugar, alcanzaría la prenda, volvería y se la entregaría a la persona que previamente le había proporcionado la "**ficha con ese código**", **H10230**

---

En informática en recuerdo al sentido de aquellas "fichas materiales", los "**tokens**" o "**fichas**", serían los "**códigos o componentes léxicos**" que aparecen escritos, figurativamente, sobre las mismas "**fichas**", es decir, la lectura sobre un grupo acotado de información (ficha), en la que aparece un código, (**H10230**), que sirve al ordenador para catalogar y organizar ciertos parámetros en la compilación.

---

De este modo, en el proceso de compilación de los programas encontramos varias fases, siendo la primera, aquella referida al "**Análisis Léxico**", donde se juntan "grupos" ("**fichas en forma figurativa**"), unidades individuales o acotadas en forma de caracteres y que por esa razón reciben el nombre de "**tokens o fichas**".

---

Un nombre para que los "tokens" en español fueran mejor asimilados podría ser "**Código Léxico de Fichas**" (clefi), "**El Componente Léxico de las Fichas**" o solo "**fichas**", en las cuales, habría que explicar, que hacen referencia simplemente al código o componente léxico que de forma figurada, aparecería escrito "sobre unos cuerpos materiales" y que desde el punto de vista informático son "grupos acotados de cadenas léxicas con significado" las cuales forman unidades individuales (como las fichas).

Answer (score 2):

[Esta documentación de IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/es/security-verify?topic=curl-oauth-access-token) usa la palabra "señal"; la misma palabra se usa en La Reina Valera (una edición de *La Biblia* muy extendida) para traducir la palabra "token" en el antiguo Testamento. Es una palabra con mucha historia...

Es similar a la [primera entrada de *señal* en el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/se%C3%B1al):

> 1. Rasgo o nota que se pone o hay en las cosas para darlas a conocer y distinguirlas de otras.

Answer (score 2):

Mi aportación, que aunque pueda ser algo genérica creo que podría ser válida, es:

> **Identificador**

Según la Wikipedia:

> Los identificadores (IDs) son símbolos léxicos que nombran entidades. El concepto es análogo al de "nombres de procesamiento de la información". Nombrar las entidades hace posible referirse a las mismas, lo cual es esencial para cualquier tipo de procesamiento simbólico.

Comment: Como ingeniero de software puedo decir que identificadores (identifiers) son distintos en la informática. Nunca se diría "identifier" cuando quieres decir "token". Un identificador sería el número en tu tarjeta de identificación emitida por el gobierno, algo bastante permanente, mientras un token sería temporal por diseño. Los usos son varios, pero un token te puede dar acceso a una página o una acción singular (como reiniciar tu contraseña) y luego se caduca. Puede identificarle a alguien de una manera, pero no se dice que es su identificador. Yo diría "ficha" igual que la respuesta aceptada.